# Point set topology question: compact Hausdorff topologies

Tags: general-topology

$\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3$ are topologies on a set such that $\tau_1\subset \tau_2\subset \tau_3$ and $(X,\tau_2)$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Could any one tell me which of the following are correct?

1. $\tau_1=\tau_2$ if $(X,\tau_1)$ is compact Hausdorff.
2. $\tau_1=\tau_2$ if $(X,\tau_1)$ is compact.
3. $\tau_2=\tau_3$ if $(X,\tau_3)$ is Hausdorff.
4. $\tau_2=\tau_3$ if $(X,\tau_3)$ is compact.

Comment: Try `\subsetneq` for strict inclusions: $\subsetneq$.

Comment: Isn't it slightly problematic to postulate that $\pi_1 \neq \pi_2$ and ask about when can $\pi_1 = \pi_2$? (Now fixed by the community editors [thanks!] but I'm leaving it up for the benefit of the OP.)

Comment: Actually I was supposed to write "tao" but I donno latex command of tao :P So I wrote $\pi$

Comment: You probably mean "tau", which is \tau and looks the following: $\tau$.

Comment: thank god! I thought it comes from  Prof.Terence Tao.

Comment: Sure, that special letter $\tau$ named after Terrence Tao.

Comment: lol that's straight up an answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** The identity mapping $(X,\tau_{i+1}) \to (X,\tau_i)$ is continuous and a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. This takes care of two statements and the two others are refuted by considering the trivial and the discrete topology on an infinite compact Hausdorff space $(X,\tau_2)$.

Comment: You meant "continuous 1-to-1 map" here, and 1-to-1ness is clear.

Comment: @hardmath: thanks, fixed.