# Show $\tau=\tau^*$ if $\tau^*\subset \tau$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,\tau)$ be compact and $(X,\tau^*)$ be a Hausdorff space. How can we show that $\tau=\tau^*$ if $\tau^*\subset \tau$?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/153734/264

Comment: Also, see Lemma 1 here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/245b-notes-10-compactness-in-topological-spaces/

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider the identity map $Id : (X,\tau) \rightarrow (X,\tau^*)$. Since $\tau^* \subset \tau$, this map is continuous. Also, a continuous map from a compact to a Hausdorff space is a closed.