# Comparing two topologies on a space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ be topologies on $X$ such that $(X, T_{1})$ is compact and $(X, T_{2})$ is Hausdorff. Show that $T_{2}$ is not a subset of $T_{1}$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153734/point-set-topology-question-compact-hausdorff-topologies?rq=1)

Comment: Does that mean we should assume that $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are not equal so that the result will follow?

Comment: Well clearly a space can be both compact and Hausdorff, so if $T_1=T_2$ the result is certainly false (since a set is always a subset of itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x$ from $(X,T_1)$ to $(X,T_2)$.

If $T_1 \subseteq T_2$, $f$ is continuous and thus a homeomorphism (as a continuous map from a compact to a Hausdorff space it will be a closed continuous bijection), and then $T_1=T_2$.